# How to enter castle archer defense?

Tags: lords-of-the-rising-sun

In *Lords of the Rising Sun* on Amiga, I play as Yoritomo (black banners with white dots) and it's been decades since I last remembered how to correctly enter the archer defense scene when an enemy sieges one of my castles. I don't think I have the original manual anymore since now I play on an emulated version licensed through Steam and Cinemaware [1].

When someone encounters a Yoritomo leader, I can pull up that leader's popup and click on the general's banner to engage. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a similar sequence to defend my castles when they are under siege. Clicking on a castle when it is under siege seems to do me no good.

When playing for Yoritomo, what steps should I take to enter the archer defense scene when one of my castles is under siege?

[1] - When I browse local Steam files, I don't see a copy of any of the manuals for the games in the Cinemaware Anthology.